# RegEx help for NotePad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need help with RegEx I just can't figure it out I need to search for broken Hashtags which have an space.

So the strings are for Example:

`#ThisIsaHashtagWith Space`

But there could also be the Words "With Space" which I don't want to replace.

So important is that the String starts with "#" then any character and then the words "With Space" which I want to replace to "WithSpace" to repair the Hashtags.

I have a Document with 10k of this broken Hashtags and I'm kind of trying the whole day without success.

I have tried on regex101.com

with following RegEx: 
 `^#+(?:.*?)+(With Space)`

Even I think it works on regex101.com it doesn't in Notepad++

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks a lot.
BR

Comment: this only finds the space between "With Space"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current regex you match a `#` and then any character and in a capturing group match `(With Space)`.

You could change the capturing group to capture the first part of the match.

[`(#+.*?)With Space`](https://regex101.com/r/tTDAPc/1)

Then you could use that group in the replacement:

`$1WithSpace`

As an alternative you could first match a single `#` followed by zero or more times any character non greedy `.*?` and then use `\K` to reset the starting point of the reported match.

Then match `With Space`.

[`#+(?:.*?)\KWith Space`](https://regex101.com/r/Ck04p7/1)

In the replacement use `WithSpace`

If you want to match one or more times `#` you could use a quantifier `+`. If the match should start at the beginning of string you could use an anchor `^` at the start of the regex.

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately with ^ in Notepad++ this is not working :(

Comment: I have added another option to my answer. Can you try the first part? Did you enable Regular expression in Notepad?

Comment: I don't know why but the search is only working without the ^ expression

Comment: @KenanTrgic `^` asserts the start of the line. Are the hashtags at the start or could they also be in the middle of a line? In that case you can omit the `^` and use [`(#+.*?)With Space`](https://regex101.com/r/tTDAPc/2) and replace with `$1WithSpace`

Comment: Yes it can be also in the middle, I tried this one but it marks to much I think 
 see the screenshot here [ScreenShot](https://i.imgur.com/855vlUn.png)

Comment: It matches to text in you example [`(#+.*?)+Aachen Brand`](https://regex101.com/r/GwMU3d/1). Then replace with `$1AachenBrand`

Comment: now the problem is that there is also HTML text which in this case is highlighted see screenshot [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/Qt4khkR.png)

Comment: Ah I see, it is [not advisable to use regex for html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). Can the tags contain a double quote? You might try this if they don't [`(#+[^"\s]+)+Aachen Brand`](https://regex101.com/r/ag1D7l/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `^(#.+?)(With\s+Space)` for your regex as it also matches multiple spaces and tab characters - if you have multiple rows that you want to affect do `gmi` for the flags. I just tried it with the following two strings, each on a separate line in Notepad++

```
#blablaWith Space
#hello#@#$aWith    Space
```

The replace with value is set to `$1WithSpace` and I've tried both replaceAll and replace one by one - seems to result in the following.

```
#blablaWithSpace
#hello#@#$aWithSpace
```

Feel free to comment with other strings you want replaced. Also be sure that you have selected the Regular Extension search mode in NPP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this? `(#.*)( )`.

I tried this in Notepad++ and you should be able to just replace all with `$1`. Make sure you set the find mode to regular expressions first.

```js
const str = "#ThisIsAHashtagWith Space";

console.log(str.replace(/(#.*)( )/g, "$1"));
```